# Ruby Thin log url it accesses

Tags: ruby, thin

Is there anyway to tell ruby to log the url it got as a request in the log?

I am seeing some crashing in my app and can't pin down what url that is doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible, but how you implement it will depend on your app. If you're using a framework like Rails or Rack use their built-in logging classes (Thin hooks into Rack's logging class automatically). If it's a vanilla Ruby script then you can include [Thin::Logging](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/doc/classes/Thin/Logging.html) in your class, which will give you `log`, `trace`, `debug`, and `log_error` methods.

As for logging the requested URL specifically, that depends entirely on your implementation.